Removing 0.0.0.0/0 as allowed IP from a Google SQL instance production
My PHP app is on a DigitalOcean droplet while my MySQL 8.0 database is on Google Cloud SQL.
I was testing for a while on localhost and hence gave 0.0.0.0/0, but now I don't want any  server other than my droplet to connect to the Google Cloud SQL instance.
Can I now safely remove 0.0.0.0/0 ?


Yes, 0.0.0.0/0 is CIDR notation and represents the entire IPv4 address space. If you have the correct (!) /32 (single IP address)  for your DigitalOcean Droplet then you should use that instead.

Communication between apps and databases can be "chatty" and, for this reason, apps are placed close to their database(s) to minimize network traffic. Separating your DigitalOcean app from its Google Cloud SQL database, may be suboptimal.

the answer to your question is yes though. If the IP address that you've obfucated is the one for your droplet, it will still be allowed to connect.

yes it should be safe, and is actually recommended to remove 0.0.0.0/0 from the allowlist.
Once this is removed you will still be able to connect from external IPs not in the whitelist using either the CloudSQL auth proxy or with SSL/TLS certificates

+1 to Cloud SQL Auth Proxy. Alternatively, you'd need to authorize the CIDR range of your droplets to be able to connect directly.
